# Angular JS $http request to webservice

Tags: angularjs, web-services, rest, jersey, jax-rs

I want to make a AngularJS $http request function that will call this method from the server side (using JAX-RS Jersey), this method consumes a JSON for a parameter and returns JSON as a result,

```
@Path("/login")
@POST
@Consumes(value = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Produces(value = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Response login(User user) {
    UserDao ud = new UserDao();
    User dariDB = ud.login(user.getUsername(), user.getPassword());
    dariDB.setPassword("");
    return Response.ok(dariDB)
            .header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")
            .header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "origin, content-type, accept, authorization")
            .header("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true")
            .header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS, HEAD")
            .header("Access-Control-Max-Age", "1209600")
            .build();
}
```

Can you help me by giving an example to the `$http` request function in AngularJS assuming the URL of the web service is "http://localhost:8084/iec3/rest/user/login" ?

Comment: Can you show what you've tried so far?

Comment: http({
    method: 'POST',
    url: 'http://localhost:8084/iec3/rest/users/login', 
    
    data:{
      nim:scope.nim,
      pass:scope.pass,
     
      },
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
       }
    }).then(function successCallback(response) {
      console.log(response.data);
      }, function errorCallback(response) {
       Flash.create('danger', 'something wrong here', 'custom-class');
       console.log(response.data);
     });


but i got the error

Comment: What exactly is the response the server is giving? Is the angular code being loaded from the same localhost:8084?

Comment: the response from the server give JSON object,,the angular code load in localhost:8000 and the server in localhost:8084

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make a request to server like as code snippet below:

```
$http({
        method: 'POST',
        url: 'http://localhost:8084/iec3/rest/user/login'
        data: user
    })
```

A full example for controller as below:

```
$scope.login = function() {
    $http({
        method: 'POST',
        url: 'http://localhost:8084/iec3/rest/user/login'
        data: user
    }).then(function(response) {
        console.log(response);
    }, function(error) {
        console.log(error);
    });
};
```

Comment: i've been try the code, but the console return error that status=0, do you know why?

Comment: Maybe your request was canceled. This is the reason for why status is zero. Are you sure http://localhost:8084/iec3/rest/user/login work correctly? Do you have test it?

Comment: i've tried  localhost:8084/iec3/rest/user/login using postman application and work correctly, i just found new issue,  if i try to make a post request without parameter, the request is success, but if using parameter the request is failed,did you know why?

Comment: What's the parameter? What's your mean for the parameter? Could you show the parameter?

Comment: Your request to the other server is being ignored since it is coming from another host and the second one does not allow cross-origin resource sharing. Look CORS up. http://www.w3.org/TR/cors/ The server on localhost:8084 must set some response headers and then the browser will be able to consume its output.

Comment: the parameter is the data which is sent from the client to server  ex. data:user, my parameter for the request is data:{username:"system", password:"admin"}

Comment: which side that should set to allow cross-origin?and if in the client side set the header ('Content-Type': 'application/json') how to set the headers on server side?

Comment: @TimotiusGunawan the server should set it. Take a look at the link I mentioned before that explains the concept of CORS.

Comment: @AnNguyen can i have your email? so i can show user class?

Comment: @h7r i'll try it and how about the client side?is still need to write headers too in angularJS request?

Comment: I think the root cause is the server couldn't parse json to object. So you can try setting application/json header for request.